# Time complexity described by recurrence relation

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I need to find the time complexity described by the following recurrence relation.

$T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + T(n/6) + n$

$T(1) = \Theta(1)$

The solution must be something like $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.

Obviously the standard form of the master theorem can't help me and any other special cases that I have found weren't useful.

Comment: Since $T(n/2) + T(n/3) + T(n/6) = 3O(n/2)$ then you can find an upper bound for that.

Comment: Use the Akra-Bazzi theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we draw recurrence tree for this relation than it would be something like following:

```
         T(n)            -> Cost: n
    /     |    \
T(n/2)  T(n/3)  T(n/6)   -> total cost: n/2 + n/3 + n/6 = n
   .
   .
  T(1) --------------->  highest depth which is about lg(n).
```

So, there are $lg(n)$ levels and every level has at least cost $n$ so $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\lg{n})$.

Now let's conjecture that $T(n) = \Omega(n\lg{n})$ and try to prove it.

---

We will prove this by induction.

Let's assume that $T(n) \ge c.n\lg{n}$ for some $c > 0$.

$T(n+1) = T(\frac{n+1}{2}) + T(\frac{n+1}{3}) + T(\frac{n+1}{6}) + n+1$

$\therefore T(n+1) \ge c.\frac{n+1}{2}.\lg{\frac{n+1}{2}} + c.\frac{n+1}{3}.\lg{\frac{n+1}{3}} + c.\frac{n+1}{6}.\lg{\frac{n+1}{6}} + n+1$

$\therefore T(n+1) \ge c.(n+1)\lg{(n+1)} + (n+1 - c.(n+1)(\frac{\lg{2}}{2} + \frac{\lg{3}}{3} + \frac{\lg{6}}{6})$

$\therefore T(n+1) \ge c.(n+1)\lg{(n+1)} + (n+1 - c.(n+1)(\frac{\lg{432}}{6}))$

$\therefore T(n+1) \ge c.(n+1)\lg{(n+1)}  \space \space \space  $

$[\because (n+1 - c.(n+1)(\frac{\lg{432}}{6}) < 0, \space \text{for } c\ge 1]$

---

Hence, we have proved that $T(n) = \Omega(n\lg{n})$ but we also have $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\lg(n))$.

So, that implies $T(n) = \Theta(n\lg{n})$.